# Symfony2 Clarification about how Form is working

Tags: symfony

On many examples i can see on the web, there is no need to get the content of a form before persist it. Example:

```
public function FormulaireAction(Request $request)
{
    $exemple= new Example();
    $form = $this->createForm('example',$exemple);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){

                      //$exemple = $form->getData(); not needed
                      $this->manager->save($exemple);
        }         
}
```

Most of the times it's true, but when i modify the data of a form into a FormEvent::SUBMIT event, like this :

```
public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event){
   $form = $event->getForm();
   $data = $event->getData();

   //find Example that fit the form data
   $exemple= $this->em->getRepository('MyExemple:exemple')->findExample($data);

   //replace with the  object location
   $form->setData($exemple);
}
```

I need to manually do a $form->getData() because the form didn't update the default object into the new one

```
public function ExempleAction(Request $request)
{
    $exemple= new Exemple();
    $form = $this->createForm('exemple_type',$exemple);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){

                        dump($exemple); //return default empty object
                        dump($form->getData()); //return the object created into the formType
        }         
}
```

**Is this a normal behavior** or am i doing something wrong ?

**Edit:** My full FormType code that reproduce the problem

```
class LocationSelectorType extends AbstractType{
public $em;
private $router;
private $options;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em,Router $router)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $em = $this->em;

    $builder   
        ->add('country','choice',array(
            'choices'=>$this->em->getRepository('MyWorldBundle:Country')->findCountryList('id'),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre pays',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-country geo-select-ajax','data-geo-level'=>'country','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))
        ->add('region','choice',array(
            'choices'=>array(),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre région',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-region geo-select-ajax hide','data-geo-level'=>'region','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))
        ->add('departement','choice',array(
            'choices'=>array(),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre Département',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-departement geo-select-ajax hide','data-geo-level'=>'departement','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))
        ->add('district','choice',array(
            'choices'=>array(),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre district',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-district geo-select-ajax hide','data-geo-level'=>'district','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))
        ->add('division','choice',array(
            'choices'=>array(),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre division',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-division geo-select-ajax hide','data-geo-level'=>'division','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))
        ->add('city','choice',array(
            'choices'=>array(),
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre ville',
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-city geo-select-ajax hide','data-geo-level'=>'city','data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),

            ))             
    ;

    $this->options = $options;
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, array($this, 'onSubmit'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPostSubmit'));

}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $location = $event->getData(); 

    //dynamilcaly fill fields     
    $this->addGeoFields($form, $location);
}    


public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData(); 

    //find or create the Location object taht fits the data
    $this->location = $this->em->getRepository('MyWorldBundle:Location')->findLocationFromStates($data);

    //dynamilcaly fill fields   
    $this->addGeoFields($form, $this->location);

}

public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();


    $event->setData($this->location);
}

public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

}

//add fields that fits the Location
public function addGeoFields(FormInterface $form, $location)
{        
    if(is_object($location) && $location->isNull()) return;        
    if(NULL == $location) return;        

    if($location->getRegion()!=NULL) $this->addGeoField($form, $location, 'region', $location->getRegion()->getId());            
    if($location->getDepartement()!=NULL) $this->addGeoField($form, $location, 'departement', $location->getDepartement()->getId());
    if($location->getDistrict()!==NULL) $this->addGeoField($form, $location, 'district', $location->getDistrict()->getId());            
    if($location->getDivision()!==NULL) $this->addGeoField($form, $location, 'division', $location->getDivision()->getId());            
    if($location->getCity()!==NULL) $this->addGeoField($form, $location, 'city', $location->getCity()->getId());
}

//add one Location field
public function addGeoField(FormInterface $form, $location, $level, $value = '')
{        
    $list = $this->em->getRepository('MyWorldBundle:Location')->findStatesListFromLocationByLevel($location,$level);
    if(empty($list)) return;

    $form->add($list['level'],'choice',array(
            'choices'=>$list['list'],
            'required'=>false,
            'mapped'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Votre '.$list['level'],
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'geo-select geo-select-'.$list["level"].' geo-select-ajax','data-geo-level'=>$list["level"],'data-icon'=>'globe','data-ajax-url'=>$this->options['ajax_url'],'style'=>"width:100%"),
            'data'=>$value
            ));
}
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'My\WorldBundle\Entity\Location',
        'ajax_url' => $this->router->generate('my_world_location_select_nextlevel'),            
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'location_selector';
}}
```

Comment: If for some reason you feel the need to change the forms data object then of course the original object is not longer useful.  But you can always just do a $exemple = $form->getData() after the isValid check without hurting anything.  The real question of course is what you feel you need to query after submitting.  But that is fine if you need to.

Comment: Ahhh ok, i think i begin to understand ! In a normal case, the form modify the default object itself, that's why it is reachable after the isSubmit(). However in my case, it is a new object that is assign to the form, so you need to recall it via $form->getData(). Thanks you very much i think i finally get it !

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$event->setData($exemple)` instead of `$form->setData($exemple)` because normalised data and denormalised data stored in separate places:

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event){
   $data = $event->getData();

   //find Example that fit the form data
   $exemple= $this->em->getRepository('MyExemple:exemple')->findExample($data);

   //replace with the  object location
   $event->setData($exemple);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i when i tried that i got a Form error "This value is not valid" and a transformationFailure with the message "Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission."

Comment: just use POST_SUBMIT event instead

Comment: or try to set not object but array... Read the documention in some moment data will be normilised. In this moment you will have an object. In another moment you will have an array. You just need to find right moment and right place to store your data.

Comment: Also you wrote that you have SUBMIT event but method name is `onPreSubmit`. Are you mistyping method name or event name?

Comment: There is no mispelling, its just a simplified code for stackoverflow^^

Comment: But you are right, POST_SUBMIT event does not trigger this error ! But there is no change in the main problem, i still need to do a $form->getData() in the controller...

Comment: And edit your question to point on the right event (in the method name or in event name).

Comment: I can't do that in PRE_SUBMIT because i can't let the form create the object from the submitted array. I had to create (or retrieve) the object myself and apply it to the form... I posted my complete code !